# android - how to select a video File using intent and getting video of it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-videoview

Im choosing the video by this code:

```
 Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 1);
```

but i dont know how to handle the result in this method:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {??????????????????????????????????}
```

can any one help me for decoding the video , i need to show it in a VideoView.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

> i need to show it in a VideoView

Call `data.getData()` to get the `Uri` of the picked video. Then, pass that `Uri` to [`setVideoURI()` on the `VideoView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setVideoURI%28android.net.Uri%29).